# Laravel's ORM sync with timestamps doesn't update timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Given the following model relationship definition:

```
public function receiptants() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

And the point in the controller where it is updated:

```
$invite->messages()->get()->each(function($item) use ($auth) {
    $item->receiptants()->sync([$auth->user()->id]);
});
```

However the timestamps remain unaltered when I inspect the tables directly. I would expect that the `updated_at` at the least be updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the touch() method manually and it will update the timestamps for you.

```
$invite->messages()->get()->each(function($item) use ($auth) {
    $item->receiptants()->sync([$auth->user()->id]);
    $item->touch();
});
```